# Ending or Cancelling a Drag Drop Operation in a Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, ole, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I am dragging and dropping email attachments from outlook.
The files are dropped into a Virtual Tree View.

My import function at the end of the drag over event takes a while to process the files and it freezes the outlook application until the function ends.

I want to be able to end the drag operation half way through the function.

```
procedure TForm.vstItemsDragDrop(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Source: TObject; DataObject: IDataObject; Formats: TFormatArray;
  Shift: TShiftState; Pt: TPoint; var Effect: Integer; Mode: TDropMode);
var
  fileList          : IStringList;
  drop              : IOleDrop;
begin
  fileList:= TIStringList.Create;

  drop := COleDrop.Create.def(DataObject);
  fileList := drop.GetDroppedFileList(fileWarnings);

  //I want to terminate the drag operator here because I already have what I need

  //This imports parts takes a while to run so I want to end the drag and drop operation
  //Outlook freezes still has cursor state on copy and doesn't respond to clicks or ESC
  ImportParts( fileList)    
end;
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't cancel from the operation until the procedure exits. What you *can* do is save the list somewhere (a variable declared in the form class declaration, for instance), post a custom message to your window handle, and then go ahead and exit the dragdrop procedure. You then process your list in a handler for the custom message you've posted to yourself afterward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually just pick up the information in the Drop event (ie. do not process it) and then send a message back to my form that there is new information to be processed. The Drop event thus exits rather quickly, and the message handler then picks up and handles whatever was dropped.

In your case, you should make something like this:

```
CONST
  WM_PROCESS_DROPPED_FILES = WM_USER+42;

TYPE
  TMainForm = CLASS(TForm)
                .
                .
              PRIVATE
                fileList : IStringList; // Ie. move the declaration here...
                PROCEDURE ProcessFiles(VAR MSG : TMessage); MESSAGE WM_PROCESS_DROPPED_FILES;
                .
                .
              END;
```

and in your drop event, remove the declaration of fileList (you have made it a private member of the form instead of a local variable) and replace

```
ImportParts(fileList)
```

with

```
PostMessage(Handle,WM_PROCESS_DROPPED_FILES)
```

then implement

```
PROCEDURE TMainForm.ProcessFiles(VAR MSG : TMessage);
  BEGIN
    ImportParts(fileList)
  END;
```

It may be necessary to make the fileList variable a TStringList instead and *copy* the information there, in case the reference to the IStringList is ended when the Drop event exits, but the general principle is the same - don't process the data in the Drop event, defer it to *after* the Drop event exits.

Comment: With this technique you can defer the processing until your message arrives in the message loop. It will still run in the main thread and block the UI, only a bit later. The user will still not be able to cancel the processing.

Comment: @OndrejKelle: Correct - but it does not block the "sending" application as well (Outlook in this case). If blocking the "receiving" application is a problem as well, then either a Queue and/or a background thread should be implemented. The essence is still the same - exit the Drop event as soon as possible to release the "lock" from the "Sending" application.